# Pyspark decision tree regressor : retrieve the path in an obervation regressor spark decision tree

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree

I'd like to know if it's possible to retrieve the path in the regression tree (pyspark) for an observation

The model code is as follows

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier, DecisionTreeClassificationModel, GBTClassifier,GBTClassificationModel
from pyspark.ml.regression import DecisionTreeRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressionModel
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator, RegressionEvaluator
dt = DecisionTreeRegressor(maxBins=10000, seed=0)

cv_dt_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(
    metricName='rmse'
    )


dt_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(
        dt.minInstancesPerNode, [100]
)\
    .addGrid(
        dt.maxDepth, [10]
)\
    .build()

cv = CrossValidator(
    estimator=dt, estimatorParamMaps=dt_grid, evaluator=cv_dt_evaluator,
    parallelism=4,
    numFolds=4
)
cv_model = cv.fit(train)
clf_best = clf.bestModel
```

Thank